# NoReverseMatch at /... With no argument not found

Tags: python, django, templates

Please at all. I'm currently facing this issue trying to redirect to previous page after form submission

**
NoReverseMatch at /studentportal/8/result/resultcreate/
Reverse for 'student_result' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['studentportal/(?P[0-9]+)/result/$']
**

Views.py

```
class ResultCreateView(CreateView ):
    template_name = 'studentportal/result_create.html'
    form_class = ResultModelForm
    queryset = StudentResult.objects.all()
    model = StudentResult
    
    
        
    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)
        
    def get_success_url(self):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('studentportal:student_result'))
```

Urls.py

```
app_name = 'studentportal'
urlpatterns = [
    path('student_list', StudentListView.as_view(), name='student_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', StudentDetailView.as_view(), name='student_detail'),
    path('create/', StudentCreateView.as_view(), name='student_create'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', StudentUpdateView.as_view(), name='student_update'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', StudentDeleteView.as_view(), name='student_delete'),
    path('<int:pk>/result/', StudentResultView.as_view(), name='student_result'),
    path('<int:pk>/result/resultcreate/', ResultCreateView.as_view(), name='result_create'),
    
]
```

Template html

```
<form method="POST" action=" ">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            
         
            <button class="regBtn">Submit</button>
        <form/>
```

Comment: in `def get_success_url(self):` reverse needs a parameter

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Kindly help me out please. I'm still new to Django

Comment: Hi Ivan. I came up with this :.  ```get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse('studentportal:student_detail', args=self.kwargs['detail']) ``` .   But I'm getting keyError at.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have `pk` arg in your path that you don't need for create as I understand. So just change you path to something like :

```
path('result/resultcreate/', ResultCreateView.as_view(), name='result_create')
```

Or even I would simplify it to

```
path('result/', ResultCreateView.as_view(), name='result_create')
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I just made the changes now and I'm still getting this error : NoReverseMatch at /studentportal/result/resultcreate/
Reverse for 'student_result' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['studentportal/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/result/$']

Comment: Sergey, please also check the action" " in the template, it has no argument as I don't know what I should pass. Thanks

Comment: I see you use rather a simple view, without much custom logic, so I would recommend you to read about `ViewSets` in DjangoRestFramework and use them instead.