# Query database in django based on specific foreignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models

please I'm having issue query database to get all the registered students under specific teacher
Model.py

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank= True)
    teacher = 'teacher'
    admin = 'admin'
    user_types = [
        (teacher, 'teacher'),
        (admin, 'admin'),
        
    ]
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=user_types, default=admin)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Student model.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfileInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='myuser')
     
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=student_image, verbose_name="ProfilePicture", blank=True)
    guardian_email = models.EmailField()
    guardian_phone = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

I have registered some students on each teacher in the database. But whenever I queried the database to list all the students under specific a teacher, I got the list of the students in the database instead

Here the views.py

```
class StudentListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'data/student_lis.html'
    queryset = Student.objects.all().order_by("first_name") 
    model= Student
```

Student_list .html

```
    {% for instance in object_list %}
   
    <li><a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }} ">{{ forloop.counter }} - {{ instance.first_name }}   {{ instance.last_name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Thanks you all

Comment: Is that field `userprofile` in the model `Student` pointing to the teacher or is it the user profile of the student?

Comment: Yes the userprofile in the student model is pointing to the teacher

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the user that accesses the view is the teacher, and you want to get all students for that teacher, you need to override `get_queryset` and return the correctly filtered queryset there:

```
class StudentListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'data/student_lis.html'
    model = Student
    ordering = "first_name"
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        teacher_profile = self.request.user.userprofileinfo # Assuming the user is the teacher
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(userprofile=teacher_profile)
```

Comment: Thanks alot man. I have updated it but I got this error:.   NameError at /data/student_list
name 'request' is not defined

Comment: @Techwithyo my bad, it should be `self.request`, edited.

Comment: Thanks. its working fine now. I'm very grateful @Abdul Aziz

Comment: Hi @Abdul Aziz. Could please help with out with the question asked here . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67566195/noreversematch-at-with-no-argument-not-found?noredirect=1#comment119426327_67566195.   Thanks